# Failed to load extension from: . Manifest file is missing or unreadable error when running Chromium instance with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, chromium

I use Selenium for UI tests. I want to run an instance of Chromium but when Chromium is opened I got a pop up with

> "Failed to load extension from: . Manifest file is missing or
>   unreadable".

Clicking ok closes the popup and leaves Chromium open with `data;.` in the address bar (screenshots https://ibb.co/Jj8McMC https://ibb.co/93hGkH7). However I am not trying to run Chrome instance with extensions, I don't need any.

```
from selenium import webdriver[![enter image description here][1]][1]

@pytest.fixture
def browser(config):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

Chromium is freshly installed from Ubuntu Software Centre and this problem does not appear when I just open the browser. Could you help?

The error I receive from pytest is:

> E       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
>   unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally E
>   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) E         (The
>   process started from chrome location /snap/bin/chromium is no longer
>   running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Comment: I don't know why but I uninstalled chromium from Software Center and installed it again via apt-get and now it's working fine.

Comment: I guess thats because software center uses SNAP. I have the same issue with chrome snap.